# Displaying additional column in a table using angularJs which is not part of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am a newbie to AngularJs. This is my scenario where I need to display a Delete button on the last column of the table which is already bound by directive?

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/QxzBu2CyIpeTObNNXHKO?p=preview][1]
```

Why do I dont see a delete option in last column?. What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive isn't all that necessary, but whatever floats your boat. Just update the template to render a delete button.

```
template: '<td>{{ item.name }}</td><td>{{ item.age }}</td><td><a href="#" ng-click="deletePerson($index);">Delete</a></td>'
```

Or you can skip the directive and go with something along the lines of:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people">
    <td>{{ person.name }}</td><td>{{ person.age }}</td><td><a href="#" ng-click="deletePerson($index);">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

then

```
$scope.deletePerson = function(index) {
    delete $scope.people[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `myElement` directive removes all child elements and replace them with its `template`.

fixed [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jkEfie7oQPZHAoO4mftG?p=preview)

```
template: '<td>{{ item.name }}</td><td>{{ item.age }}</td><td>delete</td>'
```